# After wrapping permission in a 'request' still cannot get device location

Tags: android

Using Android API version 23 and have added the permission to enable location to manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GPS_PROVIDER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Activity code to request permission at runtime :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.Manifest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager lm;
    Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                1);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                } else {

                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But this line :

```
                location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

is causing error :

[image]

I'm not setting the permission correctly ?

Update :

Here is updated code :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager lm;
    Location location;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        Log.d(TAG, "location is "+location);
        if(location != null) {
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();

            Log.d(TAG, "longitude : " + longitude);
            Log.d(TAG, "latitude : " + latitude);

        }
    }

}
```

I'm no longer receiving compiler error but `location` is set to mull.

Location is turned on within device.

Is this correct method of accessing location ?

Update 2 :

Here checking permissions with `checkSelfPermission` but `location` is null :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager lm;
    Location location;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        Log.d(TAG, "permissionCheck : " + permissionCheck);

        if(permissionCheck >= 0) {
            location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Log.d(TAG, "location is " + location);
            if (location != null) {
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();

                Log.d(TAG, "longitude : " + longitude);
                Log.d(TAG, "latitude : " + latitude);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you need to call `checkPermission` before calling `getLastKnownLocation`. It doesn't really matter that the call is happening within `onRequestPermisionResult` where we already know we've been granted the permission. I am pretty sure you need to make that check regardless.

Comment: Hi, have a look at this link: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: "have added the permission to enable location to manifest" -- there is no permission named `GPS_PROVIDER`. Remove that element from your manifest. "I'm not setting the permission correctly ?" -- you are not calling `checkSelfPermission()`, but instead are blindly calling `requestPermissions()`. My guess is that this is confusing Lint. Your approach is also user-hostile, as you will pop the permission dialog on every run, even if the user already granted it. Also, call `super.onCreate()` before calling `requestPermissions()`.

Comment: @trooper please see update

Comment: @CommonsWare please see update

Comment: "but location is null" -- well, sure. `getLastKnownLocation()` is documented to return `null` if there is no available location data. This is perfectly normal and should be covered by the material on `LocationManager` in any decent book, course, etc. Use `getLastKnownLocation()` optimistically, but be prepared for `null` and deal with it accordingly (e.g., call `requestLocationUpdates()` and work with the location fix once it is delivered to your `LocationListener`).